# Axios patch request not working with Laravel

Tags: laravel, axios

I'm trying to make a patch request from axios, but the data is not being sent.

```
const url = route('industries::update',id)

const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

return axios.patch(url,data,{ headers })
```

the data parameter is "FormData()"

I've also tried appending the key **method** with **_PATCH** in the form data

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append('method','_PATCH')
```

But nothing seems to work. I get the default laravel's 422 error from the responses (that the values are required).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st. Your data is an instance of `FormData` but your header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is wrong, use `multipart/form-data` instead. However, it will be set automatically when you use instance of `FormData` as data.

2nd. Send request via `axios.post` and append `_method: PATCH` to your `formData`:

```js
const url = route('industries::update', id)

/*
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': ' multipart/form-data' // <= instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
}
*/

return axios.post(url, data) // <= instead of `axios.patch` and omit unnecessary `headers`
```

And:

```js
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append('_method', 'PATCH') // <= instead of `('method', '_PATCH')`
```

Comment: I've also tried with 'multipart/form-data' before trying out this solution. Did not work.

Comment: It was my mistake.

It worked with 

axios.post(url,formData) // formData.append('_method','PATCH')

Thanks